# How to search with a criteria in sublime?

Tags: search, sublimetext3, criteria

in sublime if you want to search for a string "apple" but not "apple."
How do you do that?
Thank you all.

I heard somewhere you can add a - to substract unwanted hit but don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

With regular expression, you can use:

```
\bapple(?!\.)
```

Where `(?!\.)` is a negative lookahead that make sure we haven't a dot after `apple` and `\b` is a word boundary to be sure to not match `pinapple`

Comment: Thank you. Later I found out we can use general expression regex to do this kinda of stuff. I found your syntax is quite different than regex syntax though.

Comment: @ChengPeng: This is not **my** syntax, it's PCRE syntax. [See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/C6frLc/1).